# Cannot edit Grid using javascript in kendo mvc

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, telerik-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I can edit (inline mode) Grid  by typing directly using keyboard but I cannot use javascript
this is javascript( I using jquery) code:

```
$("#Quantity").val(12);
```

`Quantity` is ID of textbox which I want to edit in inline mode. I saw that value of this field changed but after click update button, the value isn't saved.

I think that Grid protect it and I don't have permission to interact from outside

Does someone knows any solutions for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found down the solution. we cannot interact from outside like

```
$("#Quantity").val(12);
```

we must add event Save

```
.Events(events =>
{
  events.Save("DetailList_Grid_Save");
})
```

and write any change in DetailList_Grid_Save function:

```
function DetailList_Grid_Save(e){
    e.model.set("Quantity", "whatever_you_want");
}
```